# What is the best way to implement a sequence of screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a sequence of screens whereby a new screen appears on click of the current one. The screen information will be of different dimensions and should fade in / out on click.  I do not require a slider. So the sequence would be like:

1. Display text
2. Fade out text to Opacity 0; display images at full opacity
3. Fade out images to 0.3 opacity and display new text over the top
4. Fade out text completely and display new images at opacity 1.0
5. etc

One way I can think of is to iterate through the screens, using jQuery animate and keeping track of the current screen with a counter variable.

Can you suggest a better design than that? Assuming I've explained my requirement sufficiently.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Got it. Removed link.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what does your source content look like; do you already have HTML elements for all the content to be sequenced through? Or are you working with some representation (XML or JSON) that you need to iterate through and generate the markup for?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything.  My thinking is to iterate through the screens, using jQuery animate and I was about to start the coding for that. I have some elements defined in HTML but not all, and I have used the animate method with previous projects.  Because I am new to web dev, I was trying to get an alternative viewpoint.